# Str replace in php?

Tags: php

I have a php page with some list of strings extracted from sql db.
Texts like:
[user:6] change color of his personal car [car:3] from 195 to 767.

I want something like str_replace and where the function found [car: car_id] and car_id as number to replace with something like [car: car_id]

Some ideas? What can I use?

Comment: I've give you a way to get the [car: car_id] with a regex. But I really don't understand what do you want to do with it...

Comment: Provide some real code and show what the result actually looks like. For example, use print_r to do a dump of what was extracted from your db. Give a specific example of what you want the new data to look like.

Answer (score 1):

To match the car id, you could use this regex: `/\[car:\s*(\d+)\]/`.

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/0ZzyiQ/4